# I can't 2 finger scroll using trackpad in Word since I upgraded to Yosemite

Tags: trackpad

I can't scroll using trackpad in Word since I upgraded to Yosemite.  I'm on a MacBook Pro.  It seems fine in all other areas, just in Word.  I have to go to the sidebar and drag it up and down to scroll.  Ideas?

Comment: What version of Word are you using? Do you have something like BetterTouchTool installed?

Answer (score -1):

You literally need to restart your computer, that should solve the problem. It did for me :)